# unit testing new objects contained within using statements

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, unit-testing, nunit

In order to make my code more testable I am wondering whether using statements such as with **SqlConnection**, **SqlCommand**, **SqlParameter** should be moved to wrapped classes?

For example I have:

```
public void setConnectionContextInfo(SqlConnection connection)
{


    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UsernameAttribute", CommonConstants.DataAccess.UsernameAttributeName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = commandBuilder.ToString();

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Would it be more correct to inject a ISqlConnectionWrapper interface such as:

```
public interface ISqlConnectionWrapper { ... }
public inteface ISqlCommand{...}
```

and then we could change the code to be more testable:

```
public void setConnectionContextInfo(ISqlConnectionWrapper connection, ISqlCommandWrapper command)
{


    using (command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UsernameAttribute", CommonConstants.DataAccess.UsernameAttributeName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

**How do you make your code more testable when faced with having to new up built-in Microsoft objects in using statements?**

Comment: While you seem to be focused on the implementation concerns, the .Net framework already has abstractions for those implementations under the [System.Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data(v=vs.110).aspx#Interfaces) namespace.

Mainly the [IDbConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx), [IDbCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand(v=vs.110).aspx), [IDbDataParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbdataparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Your method have no logic. And it seems like you want to test .NET Framework methods.

You need put all database related code behind interface.
Then you can test your business logic code.
But database code need to be tested against database and then it will be called as "Integration test"

Crete interface for all your database methods. You don't need to abstract `System.Data.SqlClient` classes, your business logic don't care are you using `Command`, `Connection`, or `Parameter` classes.

If you create wrapper interface for `SqlCommand` it means you need expose to abstraction `CommandType` enum too for example. which makes your business logic depend on the implementation.

Create interface with method which expose only business logic related data types

```
public interface IDataService
{
    void RemoveCustomer(int customerId);
}
```

So your Business logic class will use interface as dependency

```
public class CustomerManager
{
    private IDataService _service;

    // You can pass here any implementation you want
    public CustomerFactory(IDataService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    // This method now can be tested 
    // without dependencies on implementation details of data service
    public bool Remove(Customer customer)
    {
        if (customer.CanBeRemoved == true)
        {
            _service.RemoveCustomer(customer.Id);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in database layer your will implement this interface.

```
public class DataService : IDataService
{
    // Here you can freely use your implementation details
    public DataService(SqlConnection connection)
    {

    }

    public void RemoveCustomer(int customerId)
    {
        // use SqlCommand here
    }  
}
```

`DataService` class need to be tested against database, which makes test "long running", because in addition to open, close connections you need initialize preconditions and remove all changes made by code in the test.

Comment: Calls to `setConnectionContextInfo()` should be made as part of an integration test where you are actually inserting data. I agree with Fabio, there's nothing to test here.

Answer (score 0):

First. Are you realy shure that VOID method need to be tested? What exactly you wanna test there?

Second. What the reason to make this void method "public"? May be is a private method without concerns for unit-tests?

Comment: i should have used a better example, but my question was specifically towards how to inject dependencies rather than use the concrete microsoft classes

Comment: Look for the keywords in unit-testing context: "Mock", "Stub", "Fake". Different testing frameworks do it by different ways, but I think is exactly what are asked for.

Comment: Also, you can "fake" system and static things for unit testing, if you realy need it, db connetions and query results can be look as they real.

Comment: public void method need/can and must to be tested. If you use "black box" testing then it can be tested by changed state of some objects involved in the method.

Comment: Fabio has invented new unit-testing framewotk, which requires a realy private methods to be tested anyway at all cost?! =))) I don't see public method in question, it's inly mistaken marked as public